# Mi aplicación web no responde

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

Se a realizado la migración de la aplicacion Web de AWS de Amazon(Instancia Ubuntu 14.04) y bueno tenemos problemas de respuesta de las paginas luego de realizar el login salen errores que no me explico por que salen ; esta misma aplicación de manera local (ISS) y en mi otro servidor donde se encuentra si funciona no me explico cual es el problema para que no funcione; bueno acá les muestro los errores que salen; espero me puedan ayudar con este tema que ya tengo como 5 días con esto y me encuentro al preocupado porque aun no puedo dar solución. 
[image: Error 01]
[image: Error 02]

=================ADMIN_MonitoreoSAP.aspx=================

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterPrincipal.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ADMIN_MonitoreoSAP.aspx.cs" Inherits="CapaPresentacionWeb.ADMIN_MonitoreoSAP" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
     <!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"   type="text/javascript"></script>-->
     <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDNC60_dM8S-z8LaSAPz54Mb8KgGIKIMr8&callback=initMap"
 type="text/javascript"></script>


<link href="estilos/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="estilos/estilo_cliente.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="estilos/estiloImgCli.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function cambiarImg() {
        var indice = document.getElementById('s_img').selectedIndex;
        if (indice == 0) {
            $("#contenido2").css("display", "none");
            $("#contenido3").css("display", "none");
            $("#contenido1").css("display", "block");
        } else if (indice == 1) {
            $("#contenido2").css("display", "block");
            $("#contenido1").css("display", "none");
            $("#contenido3").css("display", "none");
        } else if (indice == 2) {
            $("#contenido2").css("display", "none");
            $("#contenido1").css("display", "none");
            $("#contenido3").css("display", "block");
        }


    }
</script>
```

```
 <%--    
<input type="button" class="btn-style" onclick="mostrarEstCongel();" value="Establecimientos Congelados" />
  --%>

               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_cod"  runat="server"> </asp:HiddenField>

     </nav>
     <section id="contenido">
             <div id="map"  style="width:75%;height:950px;" > </div> <!--Mapa de google maps-->

               <article id="informacion">
                <div class="tabs__links">
                    <a href="#seccion-1"> CLIENTES</a>

                    <a href="#seccion-3" onclick="mostrarEstCongel();">CONGELADAS</a>
                    <a href="#seccion-4" >STREET-VIEW</a>
                    <a href="#seccion-5" >RECORRIDO</a>
                </div>

               <div class="tabs__contents">
                    <div id="seccion-1" class="tabs__contents__item">

                    <div id="titulo_cabecera">
                          <strong>BUSQUEDA  DE CLIENTES POR COMISARIA</strong>
                    </div>                           


                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_comisarias" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_comisarias_SelectedIndexChanged">

                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">

                    </asp:ScriptManager>

                    <asp:GridView ID="gvi_AlarmasActivas" runat="server">

                    </asp:GridView>
                    <span class="title_admin_cliente">SELECCIONAR CLIENTE</span>


                    <div id="formulario" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px"> 

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_Combo" runat="server">
                      <Triggers>
                          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_comisarias" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged">
                          </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                      </Triggers>
                      <ContentTemplate>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_establecimiento" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_establecimiento_SelectedIndexChanged">

                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="congelarCliente(), mostrarEstCongel();" value="Congelar Cliente" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn"onclick="decongelarCliente(), mostrarEstCongel();" value="Descongelar Cliente" />
                    <!--<asp:Label ID="lbl_info" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>-->

                     <div id="filtrado" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px">

               <article id="busqueda_locales">
                    <span class="title_admin_cliente"> </span>
                     <span class="title_admin_cliente">BUSQUEDA DE LOCALES</span>


                    <h3>SELECCIONE EL TIPO DE FILTRO </h3>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_filtro" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Seleccione</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="1">RUC</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="2">DNI</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="3">Nro Alarma</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nrodoc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_filtrar" class="btn" runat="server" Text="Filtrar" OnClick="btn_filtrar_Click"></asp:Button>

                   <span class="title_admin_cliente">SELECCIONE ESTABLECIMIENTO</span>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_2" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_filtrar" EventName="Click"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_estComer" enableViewState="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_estComer_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </article>


                </div>
            </div>
```

========================================================================
===============================Master Page=============================

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="masterPrincipal.master.cs" Inherits="CapaPresentacionWeb.masterPrincipal" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SISTEMA DE ALERTA POLICIAL</title>
      <link href="estilos/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="estilos/estilo_cliente.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="estilos/reportes.css" rel="stylesheet" />




</head>
<body>
     <header >
            <figure id="logo">
                <img src="imagenes/pnp.png" alt="POLICIA NACIONAL DEL PERU"/>
            </figure>
            <h1>SISTEMA DE ALERTA POLICIAL</h1>


            <%--<figure id="avatar">
                <img src="imagenes/logo.png" alt="SHETecnologiadeAvanzada"/>
            </figure>--%>

      </header>

     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: coloca el código que estás haciendo funcionar :) Por cierto, bienvenido al sitio, entra a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas la funcionalidad del sitio. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Fredyfx bueno colocarte un parte del codigo basicamente donde me indica dicho error:

Comment: Hola como puedo agregar el codigo para que puedas ver donde puede estar el error que tengo,saludos; los he colocado en mi drive para que puedas tenerlos salufos

Comment: debajo de las etiquetas de tu pregunta se encuentra un enlace que dice editar, aquí lo tienes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/64674/edit

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2OY3JFyTEoUSUNpQ0VJaS15Vzg/view?usp=sharing 
Me confirmas si lo lograste descargas,gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: de nada hermano, te recomiendo que copies y pegues el código en tu pregunta :D

Comment: Hazlo posible tu ambiente de prueba/desarrollo sea lo + similar a productivo, también FrameWork. De la 1er. pantalla el elemento con ID 'hdf_cod' no lleva "</...>" colocalo de la siguiente forma: <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_cod"  runat="server" />  algunas no necesitan <"tag/asp"></"tag/asp"> simplemente <"tag/asp" />. La segunda es por que Inherits="CapaPresentacionWeb.Prueba" debe corresponder (por defualt salvo personalizaras) al CodeBehnid de asp.cs que le corresponde en su declaración; allí antes de ": System.Web.UI.Page" el nombre que le corresponderia.

Comment: Gracias @RobertoLeónOramas me sirvió